# mongo function and forEach complex query in java using MongoClient

Tags: javascript, java, mongodb

Can anyone help implement this in java using MongoClient.

```
"var arr = []
db.getCollection("A").find().forEach(function(doc){arr.push(doc.AS)})
db.getCollection("B").find( { _id: { $nin: arr}},{_id:1})"
```

From the above query i am trying to get only _id fields from "B" collection where the record in _id field of "B" does not matches to the "AS" field of "A" collection.

This code written above works well in MongoShell.

But i am not able to convert it in java driven script which uses MongoClient for conversion of queries and get value.

Comment: And why is that?

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: Not error, But i want to use this query in my java script, For this i am using mongoClient. So that i can have the result of this query in DBCursor object and which i can use further in my java code.

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 0):

Using streams and using the iterability of find() you have to do something like this:

```
// assign mongo
this.mongo = MongoClients.create(con);
// assign database
this.database = this.mongo.getDatabase(db);
// assign array from collection find all
final var arrA = StreamSupport.stream(this.database.getCollection("A").find()
        .spliterator(), false).collect(Collectors.toList());
// create projection for _id only
final var proj = Projections.fields(Projections.include("_id"));
// assign array from collection find with filter
final var arrB = StreamSupport.stream(this.database.getCollection("A").find(Filters.nin("_id", arrA))
        .projection(proj).spliterator(), false).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In the first case we collect the find without arguments which is equivalent to a find all, while in the second case we apply a filter and later a projection to return documents containing only the specified field which in this case is the _id.